# Wordpress: get content of a text widget

Tags: wordpress

I have a text widget in the left sidebar and I want it to be displayed somewhere else on the page and not in a sidebar. The widget's text is some HTML: 
`<a href...><img ...></a>`

I can't figure out the code how to get the widget's content - the HTML. I found out, that the name of the widget seems to be "text-5" using this code:

`print(wp_get_sidebars_widgets()['travelify_left_sidebar'][0]);`

Why I use a widget for this is because I want it to be easy to alter the HTML code for my client.

thx in advance,
Koem

Answer (score 2):

This template tag displays an arbitrary widget outside of a sidebar. It can be used anywhere in

```
<?php the_widget( $widget, $instance, $args ); ?>
```

Text widget

```
 <?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text', $instance, $args ); ?> 

widget's classname: widget_text
instance:
title
text
filter
Example
Default usage: 
 <?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Text' ); ?>
```

You can also find whole solution about wordpress codex site

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget